# Rails_admin Error After upgrading from 0.6.3 to 1.4 instance variable name not allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Error: `@charged?_registered' is not allowed as an instance variable name

I'm receiving this error after upgrading rails admin to the latest version, it was running fine before. It shows me the error is in this snippet of code.

```
scope :charged, -> { where.not(charge_transaction: nil) }

  rails_admin do
    object_label_method do
      :uuid
    end
    list do
      sort_by :campaign
      # filters [:campaign, :uuid]
      field :uuid
      field :campaign do
        searchable [:id, :product_name]
      end
      field :user do
        searchable [:email, :handle, { :orders => :full_name }]
      end
      field :full_name
      field :charged?
      field :shipment_id?
      scopes [nil, :currently_open, :charged, :campaign_funded_not_charged, :label_not_created, :paid_and_shipped]
    end
    configure :created_at do
      show
    end
    configure :updated_at do
      show
    end
  end

  def charged?
    return !self.open?
  end
```

Here is my console output:

```
NameError - `@charged?_registered' is not allowed as an instance variable name:
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:12:in `field'
app/models/order.rb:269:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Order>'
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config/sections.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in included'
app/models/order.rb:258:in `block in <class:Order>'
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config/lazy_model.rb:53:in `block in target'
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config/lazy_model.rb:53:in `target'
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config/lazy_model.rb:60:in `method_missing'
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config.rb:352:in `block in visible_models_with_bindings'
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config.rb:352:in `visible_models_with_bindings'
rails_admin (1.4.2) lib/rails_admin/config.rb:320:in `visible_models'
```

Any Idea how I can fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

Since `charged?` is a method and not an attribute on the object, you could configure it this way:

```
field :charged do
  formatted_value do
    bindings[:object].charged?
  end
  label do
    'Charged?'
  end
end
```